# How to fix 'Missing requirement' error in Maven on Windows

Tags: maven, slf4j, tycho, dbeaver

I'm trying to build [dbeaver](https://github.com/dbeaver/dbeaver) and get the following error when running `mvn package`:

```
[ERROR] Cannot resolve project dependencies:
[ERROR]   Software being installed: org.jkiss.dbeaver.slf4j 1.0.0.qualifier
[ERROR]   Missing requirement: org.jkiss.dbeaver.slf4j 1.0.0.qualifier requires 'bundle org.slf4j.api 0.0.0' but it could not be found
```

I'm running on Windows 10 and using apache-maven-3.6.1. The strange thing is that when I try the same steps on Linux it builds without problem.

Comment: Are you using the most recent dbeaver/devel branch?

Comment: I ran git clone https://github.com/dbeaver/dbeaver.git just before I ran the build.

Comment: I'm having the same issue on Windows after `git pull --ff-only`. I can't even `mvn clean`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Update**

Possible cause is maven 3.6.1 https://www.eclipse.org/lists/tycho-user/msg08177.html

**Original post**

The problem here, I presume, is that https://dbeaver.io/eclipse-repo/ p2 site is missing slf4j bundle and Tycho (?) cannot resolve the requirement. I still do not know how to make standalone maven build work, but here is an ugly workaround on how to build Windows binary with Eclipse (and embedded maven).

You can use *p2-maven-plugin* to build that missing bundle yourself. Instead of setting up a brand new project, you can temporarily modify `product\localRepository\pom.xml` to have a single artifact like

```
...
<artifacts>
  <artifact><id>org.slf4j:slf4j-api:1.7.26</id></artifact>
</artifacts>
...
```

Now build that (`product\localRepository\`) project and start jetty

```
mvn p2:site
start mvn jetty:start
```

Now <del>you can add this interim update site (`http://localhost:8080/site/`) to your Eclipse installation (Help -> Install New Software) and install slf4j. You should already be able to run DBeaver from within Eclipse.</del>

<del>To build a binary,</del> add this interim repo into main pom.xml file, e.g. right after *local-contrib* one.

```
    <repository>
        <id>more</id>
        <url>http://localhost:8080/site/</url>
        <layout>p2</layout>
    </repository>
```

Then go to Run Configurations -> Maven Build -> dbeaver, enter *package* goal and tick *Skip Tests*, click Run and go have some coffee.

[image]

As you can see Eclipse uses some sort of embedded maven runtime, so I guess it resolves things differently.

**Note** that if you are updating your local git repo, you might need to update your Eclipse project big time. I was unable to do it with right clicking on the project -> Configure -> Configure and Detect Nested Projects :( But deleting Eclipse project and nested projects (without deleting underlying files) and re-importing Maven project did the trick for me.

There is also an open issue for this https://github.com/dbeaver/dbeaver/issues/6115 .

Comment: Downgrading to maven 3.6.0 solved the problem. I was also able to build the project with Eclipse too, using the steps described here: https://github.com/dbeaver/dbeaver/wiki/Develop-in-Eclipse

Comment: Yeah, Eclipse build should have just worked as per Wiki. For whatever reason, quite often after `git pull --ff-only` I get lots of odd issues in Eclipse. Either way, good to be back on track.